# Is it possible to count something from general container in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have an `object`.

This object is casting an `Items Container` (I don't know what items, but I can check).

But is there any code which can help me find how many items it contains?

I mean

```
 object[] arrObj = new object[2] {1, 2};
 object o = (object)arrObj;
```

In this case `arrObj` is an array so I can check:

`((Array)o).Length` //2

But what if I have  those 2 others ?

```
 ArrayList al = new ArrayList(2);
           al.Add(1);
           al.Add(2);
 object o = (object)al ;
```

and

```
 List<object> lst= new List<object>(2);
 object o = (object)lst;
```

Is there any general code which can help me find how many items are in this casted object (`o` in this samples) ?

Of course I can check `if (o is ...)  { }` but Im looking for more general code.

Comment: so you want to be able to count how many items o contains?

Comment: how many items does the object which is casted to object contains. yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the most basic interface it could implement would be `IEnumerable`. Unfortunately even `Enumerable.Count` from LINQ is implemented for `IEnumerable<T>`, but you could easily write your own:

```
public static int Count(IEnumerable sequence)
{
    // Shortcut for any ICollection implementation
    var collection = sequence as ICollection;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Count;
    }

    var iterator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable = iterator as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is basically equivalent to:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (object item in sequence)
{
    count++;
}
```

... except that because it never uses `Current`, it wouldn't need to do any boxing if your container was *actually* an `int[]` for example.

Call it with:

```
var sequence = container as IEnumerable;
if (sequence != null) 
{
    int count = Count(sequence);
    // Use the count
}
```

It's worth noting that avoiding boxing really is a bit of a micro-optimization: it's unlikely to really be significant. But you can do it *once*, just in this method, and then take advantage of it everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast to the interface every container implements: `IEnumerable`. However, to be more performant, it is a good idea to first try `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var count = -1;
var enumerable = lst as IEnumerable<object>;
if(enumerable != null)
    count = enumerable.Count();
else
{
    var nonGenericEnumerable = lst as IEnumerable;
    count = nonGenericEnumerable.Cast<object>().Count();
}
```

For `Count()` to be available, you need to add `using System.Linq;` to your .cs file.

Please note that this code has one big advantage: If the collection implements `ICollection<T>` - like `List<T>` or strong typed arrays of reference types - this code executes in O(1) <sub>[Assuming the concrete implementation of `ICollection<T>.Count` executes in O(1)]</sub>. Only if it doesn't - like `ArrayList` or strong typed arrays of value types - does this code execute in O(n) and additionally, it will box the items in the case of an array of value types.

Comment: `ArrayList` does not implement `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: This code has the *disadvantage* that it boxes every item in an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a value type though. (I've edited my answer to handle the case where it's an ICollection implementation, which is the vast majority of `ICollection<T>` implementations.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Are you talking about `lst is int[]`? Are you sure it boxes? The cast to `IEnumerable<object>` shouldn't actually be doing anything and the `Count()` doesn't access the items either, because it uses `ICollection<T>.Count`. Even with `ArrayList` no boxing should occur, because the items are already boxed. I don't see where it boxes. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Why would the cast not do anything? The result of calling `Cast<object>` on an `int[]` is a `System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__b1`1[System.Object]` (I've just tried). Logically, as you iterate over the `int[]`, it has to box each item that you retrieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet: But a `Cast<object>` on an `int[]` would never happen, because `int[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are of course correct. Althought `int[]` implements `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant,  `lst as IEnumerable<object>` will still return `null` because `int` is a value type and thus this cast is not legal. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Exactly. Lack of variance over value type type arguments strikes again :(

Comment: @JonSkeet but also this code ((IEnumerable)o).Cast<object>().Count(); will box each value element .right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes - that's basically the same as Daniel's last line. That's why my answer takes a different approach :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use linq.

```
var count = ((IEnumerable)o).Cast<object>().Count();
```

Ensure that the type `o` has implements `IEnumerable` and that you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file.

Comment: Might not perform well (always O(N)) but is a simple solution.

Comment: You could check if if(TypOf(o) == IEnumerable)

Comment: @DanielA.White It should be something close to that i think

Comment: the `is` operator is what the OP needs.

Comment: @RoyiNamir only if its a value type.